# LIT File Viewer for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, ebook

I know that LIT files can be converted to HTML files on a Mac, but is there an actual lit file viewer for Mac analogous to MS ebook reader?

Answer (score 3):

I have been using Stanza to read .lit files. Check it out.

Comment: Thanks; can you please add the link in your answer? http://www.lexcycle.com/download-macintosh

Comment: I just checked it. The rendering is very bad. :-(

Comment: No I can't add a link to my answer: last time I did, all but 1 point were deducted from my account. Oh my hard-earned points :-(

Answer (score 3):

**[calibre](http://calibre.kovidgoyal.net/)** is a **one stop solution to all your e-book needs**. It is free, open source and cross-platform in design and works well on Linux, **OS X** and Windows.

supported formats: CBZ, CBR, CBC, EPUB, FB2, HTML, **LIT**, LRF, MOBI, ODT, PDF, PRC**, PDB, PML, RB, RTF, TCR, TXT Output Formats: EPUB, FB2, OEB, LIT, LRF, MOBI, PDB, PML, RB, PDF, TCR, TXT

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried calibre on OSX and it is really slow and sluggish. Plus, it does not render broken HTML well enough. For example, in a LIT the entire book content was underlined (unclosed <u> tag? IE would have rendered it well)

Comment: LIT is always tricky unless you're using MS REader, i avoid this format like the plague ... other than that i can only think of a VBox with XP + MS REader for your Mac

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://macosx.com/tech-support/mac/opening-lit-files-in-mac-os-x-10-4/24890.html)

[convertlit](http://www.convertlit.com/) will be able to open .lit files (which are Microsoft-format- eBook files),

**or**

Downloaded [ABC Amber Lit Converter](http://download.cnet.com/ABC-Amber-LIT-Converter/3000-2248_4-10790652.html) (Windows) and converted to PDF on my Windows computer, then transferred them over to Mac